# Char mask, or get char size in vala?

Tags: vala

I need all bits to 1 on a char size, while I know in C there is limits.h, and vala has int.MAX, I’m not sure of the char size.

How could I find it - *a char size* - and generate my bitmask for sure, instead of using 0xFFFF ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vala, `char` is one byte. Here is the VAPI declaration:

```
[IntegerType (rank = 2, min = 0, max = 127)]
public struct char {
```

Answer (score 3):

apmasell is right, but I don't really like his answer.  If you want the size of char (in bytes), you should use `sizeof(char)` instead of depending on that value in the glib vapi staying the same.

`char.MAX`, if it existed, wouldn't be 0xff (255), it would be 0x7f (127), but that isn't the right value for a mask since the.  From a practical perspective it's probably safe to assume 0xff is the right value, but if you want to be safe you could just use `~((char) 0)`.

Comment: Well tank you for theses info, I the mean time i ended up using ```const uchar CHARMAX = 0xFF;```, since this what i was actually looking for. I guess i will now use ```const uchar CHARMAX = ~((uchar) 0);```

Comment: FWIW, it would probably be more appropriate to use uint8 instead of uchar.  If what you're dealing with isn't actually an unsigned character (and, based on the fact that you're using a bitmask I doubt it is) then you should just use the appropriate integer type.  It is common to use char in C because, until C99, it was basically the only way to get a very small integer (smaller than short), but Vala doesn't have that issue.